# How to invoke a method from a modal view controller class in Swift?

Tags: swift

Basically for this simple game app I have 2 different UIViewControllers called ViewController and PreviewController. PreviewController is opening view with the title screen and a label titled "Start game". When the label is tapped, it initiates a modal view controller (the ViewController class that has all the views for the actual game itself) and calls the "EnterNewGame" method from ViewController that sets up the game. Right now the issue I have is when calling this method, only part of the method seems to be running.

Here is the function in PreviewController that is being initiated upon tap:

```
@objc func handleButtonTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.present(ViewController(), animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
        ViewController().enterNewGame()
    })
}
```

And here is the EnterNewGame() method from ViewController

```
func enterNewGame() {
    //show suit indicators when starting a new game
    bluePlayerSuitsHidden = false
    redPlayerSuitsHidden = false

    game.blueTurn = true
    self.setBackground()
    self.cleanUpBoard()
    self.createBoard()
    self.displayBoard()
    self.setSuitIndicators()
    self.highlightCards()
    playButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

Right now, when the label is tapped the screen transitions to the modal view controller but only displays a black screen with only one of the game setups (setting a few images on the top of the screen) working properly. I am sure that the EnterNewGame method works properly to actually start the game because I have tested it in isolation, so I think I am just not setting up the modal view controller properly or I have to call the method differently. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller on which you're calling your method ins't the same instance as controller which you're presenting, you need constant (also your code can be simplified by avoiding using `self` references and writing name of `completion` parameter with specifing closure's parameter and return type)

```
@objc func handleButtonTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let controller = ViewController()

    present(controller, animated: true) {
        controller.enterNewGame()
    }
}
```

Also, you can call this method on some other method inside your certain controller like `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or you can create factory method which would return you certain set controller.

This last part leads me to idea: look how you instantiate your controller and look carefully if you don't need to instantiate it through storyboard or nib file.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    class func instantiate() -> ViewController {
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as! ViewController
        // let controller = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
        controller.enterNewGame()
        return controller
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
@objc func handleButtonTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    present(ViewController.instantiate(), animated: true)
}
```